# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Pass parameter to JSONStore load function

Tags: adapter, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I want to load a JSONStore based on a provided param to the adapter mapped load function. 
Let me explain it better.

The JSONStore initialization is like this:

```
collections[EMPLOYEE_COLLECTION_NAME] = {

    searchFields : {ENAME: 'string', EMPNO:'integer'},

    //-- Start optional adapter metadata
    adapter : {
        name: 'EmployeesDB',
        add: 'addEmployee',
        remove: 'deleteEmployee',
        replace: 'updateEmployee',
        load: {
            procedure: 'getEmployee',
            params: [region],
            key: 'resultSet'
        }
    }
    //-- End optional adapter metadata
};


//Initialize the people collection
WL.JSONStore.init(collections, options)
```

As you can see in the code above, even after the param region was passed to the adapter collection init, is it supposed to change during my app life cycle, so there are moments where region let's say is SOUTH, others is NORTH and so on.

I realized that even though I change this value after the store was created, the mapped load function in the adapter getEmployee (see below) always get value that region contained at the time the jsonstore was initialized regardless I change the region variable value later on. Looks like the adapter binds conf is getting at collection creation time, and never changes it

```
function getEmployee(data) {
    WL.Logger.info('Show param:'+data); 
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : selectStatement,
        parameters : []
    });
}
```

Is there a way to pass parameter to the Jsonstore load function that can change after the store was initialized ?

I wanted to avoid close and init the collection again to save time and resources.

By the way, what I really need is to have flexibility on what I load from the database based on a adapter parameter that is bound to a collection.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

```
WL.JSONStore.get(EMPLOYEE_COLLECTION_NAME).adapter.load.params = ['...']
```

Before calling `WL.JSONStore.get(EMPLOYEE_COLLECTION_NAME).load()`.

If you want more flexibility, you can always call `WL.Client.invokeProcedure` and inside the `onSuccess` callback you can call: `WL.JSONStore.get(EMPLOYEE_COLLECTION_NAME).add(['...'], {push: false})`. The `push: false` section will make sure JSONStore understands that the data added is up-to-date with the data on the backend. This means it won't show those documents when you call: `WL.JSONStore.get(EMPLOYEE_COLLECTION_NAME).getPushRequired()` or `WL.JSONStore.get(EMPLOYEE_COLLECTION_NAME).push()`.